# Change encoding of an xml file in php

Tags: php, xml, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I have opened a server which is waiting for queries. 
When i send a query, the server will answer it and safe the results in an xml file.
Problem is, that I can't use this xml properly because in the first line of the xml is now written:

xml version="1.0 encoding="utf-8"

if I change this in the editor into:

xml version="1.0 encoding="iso-8859-1

than it works fine.
But instead of using editor and my hands, i want php to do it?
Thx

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: Actually, i can't see the code, cause someone else wrote it. I use exec("curl "http://localhost:8888/?q=queryToSearch" > "patch/to/file/result.xml" ) The xml gets generated but it gets generated in utf-8 encoding, i want to change it in iso-8859-1

Comment: Why do you don't use str_replace(str,'utf-8','iso-8859-1') ?

Comment: thx man :) working, don't get why i didn't thought about that *fixed*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close the question:
I used str_replace(str,'utf-8','iso-8859-1') in the xml file, which helped me to open the xml file in the right way.
Thx to you